# Port forwarding error: Port forwarding is not forwarding to server

Tags: c++, networking, portforwarding

So, I have made a client and a server in c++. My server has a port set to htons(54000). My client has port htons(54000) as well.

My problem is that when I try to connect my client to my machine(where my server is hosted on, machines ip is: e.g. 80.60.117.24), nothing happens at all!

I have found out that I need to use port forwarding. My router is a Huawei B525 - 23. I have tried to port forward from WAN-port 54000 to LAN-port 54000 and my machine's local ip: 192.168.8.50.

Well, it doesn't work.

Though it works whilist the server and the client is on the same LAN. (I set the ip-address the server has on the client to 192.168.8.50(my machine, server is hosted on here)).

//SERVER.cpp

```
    sockaddr_in hint;
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(54000);
    hint.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("0.0.0.0");
    bind(listening, (sockaddr*)& hint, sizeof(hint));
    listen(listening, SOMAXCONN);
```

//CLIENT.cpp

```
string ipAddress = "80.60.117.24"; // IP Address of the server
int port = 54000;
sockaddr_in hint;
hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
hint.sin_port = htons(port);
```

So, what am I doing wrong? How am I forwarding the ports wrong?

Comment: You say `80.60.117.24` is the server machine's IP. Did you mean that it is your router's public WAN IP?  Your client needs to connect to the router's public WAN IP:Port, then the router needs to forward from that IP:Port to the server's LAN IP:Port.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau 80.60.117.24 is not my routers ip. I just tried with my routers public WAN IP. That didn't work either :(.

Comment: then you don't have your forwarding setup correctly. The server code you showed is fine, if the client connects to the router's WAN IP:Port and the router forwards to the server's LAN IP:Port then the connection will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. The thing I did was just hosting the server on a different network (I have 2 connections in my house). Port forwarding was set up correct. Thank you both for good help and sorry for my hard descriptions. :)

Answer (score -1):

Let me see if I understand the scenario. Is the client you are connecting to the server using the same internet connection as the server?
You setting the IP to the same subnet allowing the traffic to work makes me think this is the scenario.
If that is the case, then it may not be working because the traffic would route outward to your router. The router would look at it and say that it has that traffic on an external NAT. It would route the traffic to the NAT, which would in turn apply your port forwarding rules.
The challenge is that when the server responds, it will be responding to the NAT address not the LAN address. When that traffic hits the router, the port forwarding will again grab the traffic and send it to the server. So that the client gets to the server, but the server only ends up talking to itself.
I would try the connection from a different location (as in different internet connection). If that works, then you know that you have this loop happening.
That being said, as @RemyLebeau pointed out, generally you will not have the public IP on your server, unless you have a range of public IPs and your router's public IP is different from that of your server's. If you do have a separate public IP for the server, then make sure that the router's WAN port and the server are on the same VLAN. So you would have to bring the traffic in on a switch to an isolated VLAN that does not have a VIP setup. It is pretty risky to have your server completely exposed like that though.
If you have your server set to the same IP as your router, then you have an entirely different issue. 
You will want your server's IP to be something on the local LAN and the PAT set to forward traffic to that local IP. So if your machine has 192.168.8.50, then your server might have 192.168.8.40. Something static, which is not in the DHCP range, and that is within the subnet (I assumed a /24 network - 255.255.255.0).
Hopefully this was helpful.
If I missed the mark or your setup is different from any of these scenarios, then please give more detail on the topography of your network configuration.

Comment: Thank you for that answer. Unfortunately, it didn't help me, but I can see that I was a little unclear in my scenario.

The scenario is that my client is being run on a different internet to the internet my server is hosted on. And my server is being hosted on my machine(80.60.117.24) on a different internet to the one the client is being run on. I just tried to connect the client to then WAN-ip address(which is the one my server is running on), and that did not work either.
I have, on the internet the server is hosted on, set up port forwarding to my local machine(server host 192.168.8.50)

Comment: @YouveGotANewNotification your description is still a little hard to understand. Can you please edit your question to provide a diagram of your actual network layout showing where each machine and router is located in relation to each other and which device has which IP assigned to it?

Comment: Why would the server be talking to itself? You seem to think that NAT doesn't actually work.